# MySQL primary key column type for large tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, schema

I'm working on the project with relatively big DB table(**700K rows**).

Mistake, I've made while designing DB schema.
When rows were increasing, I had to increase ID's column type bigint(**x**).

Now it is bigint(44).
I afraid of setting high x value because I thought that it can significantly slows down performance. Maybe I'm wrong..

Please help me in solving the problem.

What column type can I set once and forget about this issue?

What should I learn better in field of DB schema design?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you create a column as `BIGINT(44)` the "44" is the display width - it does not affect the range of values you can store or the speed at which they are retrieved.

For an auto-incrementing ID you want to use an `UNSIGNED` number, e.g. `BIGINT(44) UNSIGNED`.  This will double the range of values and add an extra constraint, which is usually a good thing.

An unsigned INT will store up to:

> 4,294,967,295

An unsigned BIGINT will store up to:

> 18,446,744,073,709,551,615

you're not going to fill that any time soon.

You don't say how fast your maximum ID is growing - if you're not inserting many rows then you should stick with `UNSIGNED INT` as it takes less space.

Answer (score 1):

I think any primary key will be unsigned by default. In any case, using negative numbers for primary keys is frowned upon at best, and breaks stuff.

Comment: Could you please be more specific?  "breaks stuff" is pretty vague.  What exactly does it break?