# Alternative for long data type as a primary key in mysql

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I have table in which we are inserting too many records per day. The table has a long columns as a primary key. Now in past 2 year its already exhausted 50% of the LONG range.  (Java's `LONG` maps to MySQL's `BIGINT`.)  I am looking for other data which we can use as a primary key.
what can we the other options, What I am think of creating a new table, with similar structure for a non-sequencial primary key. But I dont have any idea how to achieve this without performance it.

What I am think of creating a new table, with similar structure for a non-sequencial primary key. But I dont have any idea how to achieve this without performance it.

Comment: Primary key can also be of multiple columns.

Comment: @prasad_ by my primary is referenced in other table.  I cannot embed composite key in the other table for reference

Comment: Also see these Stack Overflow posts: [MySQL primary key column type for large tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816646/mysql-primary-key-column-type-for-large-tables) and [MySQL PRIMARY KEYs: UUID / GUID vs BIGINT (timestamp+random)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338956/mysql-primary-keys-uuid-guid-vs-bigint-timestamprandom).

Comment: There is no LONG data type.  For an integer type for very large tables, use unsigned BIGINT, which allows up to 18446744073709551615, which should be sufficient for almost any purpose.

Comment: MariaDB 10.4 (2019) will automatically provide a HASH for uniqueness.  `UNIQUE KEY ... USING HASH`.

Comment: "exhausted 50% of the LONG range" -- Are you talking about C 32-bit "long" datatype?

Comment: @ysth yes yo are right. I am using JAVA JPA which is convert java LONG to mysql BIGINT data type. both are equal

Comment: there's no way you have used 50% of the BIGINT range in 2 years; that would take 14 billion records per second.

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not image) output of `show create table yourtablename`

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying that your 32-bit `INT` is threatening to overflow, then the simplest solution is to

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

It will take a loooooong time if there are a billion rows.

(If you mean something else by "LONG", please explain.)

Comment: As I explained in the problem my primary its already a LONG and its range is about to finish in next 7-8 months. so I am looking for alternative for the same. So Java LONG datatype is transfered to BIGINT of mysql

Comment: Are you saying that Java's LONG is a 64-bit datatype?  (I haven't touched Java in 24 years.)  What do you get from `SELECT MAX(id) FROM tbl`?

Comment: 45560427 , table is just 3 month old.

Comment: @deadprogrammer - At that rate, it will take more than a decade to overflow MySQL's `INT SIGNED`.  Unless you are working for the govt, you will rewrite the app before then.

Comment: @deadprogrammer - Another thing -- How many rows in the table (`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl`)?  If it is a lot less than 45560427, then you are deleting and/or burning ids.  In that case, tell me more; I may have ways to avoid growing the ids so fast.

Comment: table has insert and update operations only. There is no delete operation.

Comment: Yeah, but `INSERT IGNORE` can "burn" ids.  So there _may_ be fewer than 45560427 _rows_.